# What should be optimal keepalive time for whatsapp type messenger on MQTT protocol?

Tags: mqtt, instant-messaging

I am trying to implement a messenger for 2G connection speed and low end android phones. Thats why I am using MQTT protocol to implement something like whatsapp.

What should be an an optimal keepalive time given that messenger is targetted for not-so-good notwork?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely down to how unreliable the network is and how much latency you can live with on any given message.